# Joomla! alternative registration form switches back to default form

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am following the "Joomla! Programming" book by Mark Dexter and Louis Landry.

I came up to the point where we create a plugin to check whether both terms of service agreement and age above 18 is checked in the alternative registration form layout which we create earlier (approval.php).

When testing this plugin, I checked only one of the checkboxes and showed the "Registration Failed" error as expected. But on the error page, the registration form is the default one and not the alternative one which we created earlier (approval.php)

Why is this?

Comment: Please share a snippet of code to have a better look at it.

Comment: It sounds like the redirect is not right.

Comment: Can you provide that piece of code..what is the alternative registration form action url? Also what are the hidden elements in the form?